# Problemas para compilar webpack y Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

este es el error que me arroja al tratar de hacer npm run build, y cuando hago npm start abre el código en blanco el problema parece estar en la entrada pero no puedo ver el error.

> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Plugin/Preset files
>   are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In
>   C:\Users\mmares\Documents\proyectos-telenet\boletin\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry:  './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(\.js|.jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                   loader: 'babel-loader'
               }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'json-loader'
               } 
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entiendo que es un app que usa reactjs, por lo tanto falta una parte del build.

El flujo es algo asi:

**Webpack**

Construye un arbol de dependencias, es decir, recorre toda tu aplicacion y entiende que archivos necesitas y arma un paquete de uno o pocos archivos. Al recorrer todos los archivos tambien los transforma a algo que webpack entienda, es decir, javascript.

**Babel**
Es una libreria que compila/transforma javascript para que puedas programar usando elementos experimentales o avanzados del lenguaje, y tener como resultado un codigo que funciona en la mayoria de navegadores actuales.

**React**

Es una libreria que esta enfocada en renderizar tu interfaz grafica de manera eficiente. Puedes usar react usando javascript basico (Por ej. `React.createElement("")`) o mas comunmente usando jsx (`<MiComponente />`).

Cuando webpack carga archivos jsx, no los entiende pues `<MiComponente />` no es javascript, entonces necesitamos decirle al loader de jsx que los transforme usando babel a un javascript que webpack pueda entender.

Para lograr esto debes instalar estos modulos via `npm`:

```
npm i @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

y en la configuracion de webpack:

```
 ...
 {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
        plugins: []
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Hola, estoy intentando hacerlo de esa forma y no me salio.

Comment: Puedes darnos mas informacion sobre el error?